# Is loading html into a html file common practice?

Tags: html

I'm currently building a website for fun, and I'm wondering if one should load HTML files into a HTML file. For example, I have my index.php file and a navigation bar. Since this navigation bar should be included in all pages, I want to 'import' it so I only have to change the navigation bar file if changes should be made to the navigation bar.

I have tried a few ways, but they all give me some warning in my console (google Chrome) about being deprecated. I have tried:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#includeNav').load("navbar.html");
    });
</script>

<div id="includeNav"></div>
```

And:

```
<div w3-include-html="html_includes/navbar.html"></div>
```

And:

```
<div data-include="/html_includes/navbar.html"></div>
```

Most of the times I get an error like this: "jquery.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."

Two questions:

1. What is the right way to do this in 2020?
2. Is including HTML files into a HTML file common practice or not?

Comment: Since you are using php why not make one php file which includes a layout for the page and a dynamic content section? No I would not imagine including html files into html file is common practice.

Comment: You could redirect requests with .htaccess and use one controller php file to generate the page. It would include header, navbar, content and footer separately. There are also plenty of php frameworks and template engines which would achieve such a thing with ease.

Comment: Basically you could use a backend template engine or a frontend javascript framework with data binding. There is blade template engine and smarty for backend which are really good. Then the usual AngularJS, ReactJS for the front. Those are designed exactly for this kind of problem.

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. You can switch to a SPA framework, but I don't see any advantages with your approach, only disadvantages that affect the UX and SEO

Comment: I see here technologies you are using but I don't understand you want to do it with with JavaScript or PHP

Comment: People do all sort of terrible things so being common or not is not a relevant point. As said, you're already using a server-side preprocessor (PHP) that can do everything in a single HTTP request. You can certainly use client-side templating engines, at the cost of additional requests but with the potential of caching stuff. They're simply different tools for the same thing, each with its pros and cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extension .php instead of .HTML of web pages.Because in .php extension you can use **require**  and **include**  functions.

Here's a documentation [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)  !

**Require Syntax**

```
<?php require 'navbar.php';
echo "Add navbar";
?>
```

**include Syntax**

```
<?php include 'navbar.php';
echo "Add navbar";
?>
```